# Walk/Car mode detection through skobbler API

Tags: ios, skmaps

I want to implement a functionality in my iOS app that detects if the user is Walking or driving. Is there a way i can detect the modes in Skobbler. I am using the Skobbler 2.1. Please suggest something. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are navigating on a route then the used routing profile might be a good indicator of travel mode.

If you are in "free drive" mode then the only metric you get is the current speed - above a certain threshold you may assume that the user is driving (or biking?). Other than these 2 things I don't know what else you could do.